# How to properly fetch data from API in vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuex

I'm working on my Vue.js application and having a trouble with fetching data via API with vuex-router-sync.

As I saw in every tutorial or sample, it is common thing to dispatch the store action on `created` component hook. In my case it doesn't seem to be an option and here's why:

I use the standard vue-router for my routing, and when I navigate between pages not only my content should change, but also my sidebar and header. Thus I implemented the named router-view concept, such as

```
    routes: [{
      path: '/',
      components: {
        page: Home,
        sidebar: GeneralSidebar,
        header: HomeHeader
      }
    }, {
      path: '/game/:id',
      name: 'game',
      components: {
        page: Game,
        sidebar: GameSidebar,
        header: GameHeader
      }
    }]
```

But the Game, GameHeader and GameSidebar should share the same getter for the currently selected game. It's impossible to decide, which one of those components should be dispatching the action to fetch the data.

I tried to hook on the router itself, on `beforeEnter`, but faced the issue, that navigating between the same routes (in my case from `/game/1` to `/game/2`) does not trigger the `beforeEnter`.

Is there any way that I can hook on *any* route navigation? Or maybe a better pattern for dispatching fetch-actions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find a solution? Having the same issue now, wondering what concept actually works

Comment: @Conic, if still curious, see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. For example You could fetch data inside some component which is loaded by route change and after set data to vuex by dispatching change. This does the job perfectly. Also keep in mind that there are few ways to fetch data inside any component - You can hook that in any of Vue lifecycle hooks. Take a look here https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/data-fetching.html

Also sometimes You need some data upfront of any route change and here You can use the same approach - make some request when Vue app is loaded.